# Core Signing + Hardening runtime of .net core app on MAC

Tags: macos, .net-core, code-signing, notarize

I have created a sample .net core worker service app. I want to code-sign the app on MAC, but I get the below error :

> - Your Mach-O executable does not conform to modern Mach-O layout
>     rules.
> - You may be using a third party development product that
>     hasn't been brought up to date, or post-processed your file in
>     unsupported ways.

Below are the publish parameters provided while creating the executable:

[image]

I have added UseAppHost as true in the csproj file. But sill get the same issue

```html
<UseAppHost>true</UseAppHost>
```

Comment: Macos version??

Comment: @RichardBarber: macOS 10.15 Catalina

Comment: did you get any solution on this?

Comment: @RichardBarber did you know the solution of this?

Comment: Double check the binary executable has the Executable bit set.

Answer (score 0):

seems to be a .net issue with single file, should be fixed in .NET 6 https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/3671